# ISRC on track objects

Tags: spotify

I'm aware that [not every endpoint provides an ISRC code for tracks](https://github.com/spotify/web-api/issues/182). But can it be assumed with **certainty** that every track has an ISRC code when queried directly from the `https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks` endpoint? Are there cases where no ISRC is provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no guarantee that the ISRC code is provided for every track, so your application should be able to handle when it isn't available.

Comment: Thank you, is there any way to link all versions of the same track without an ISRC?

Comment: It's possible to find other releases of the same track. What's your use case?

Comment: The use case is storing metadata on a track regardless of what version/market of the track is sent up. The issue is how to identify on our backend if we already have a version/market of that track in our database.

Comment: I see. Well, you could use Track Relinking to figure out if there are other versions out there in case you're looking for a particular market, https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/track-relinking-guide/, or use the search endpoint to find tracks with similar names. It's not perfect, but it could help.